# Where can I see the XAMPP database?

Tags: xampp

I'm a beginner and I'm having trouble finding the XAMPP database.

Where can I see the XAMPP database?

Comment: You don't have to apologize, we were all beginners at some point. The best way to learn is ask questions. Just make sure they are clear and concise so people here can answer them effectively :D

Answer (score 6):

XAMPP comes bundled with phpmyadmin. It should be at http://localhost/phpymadmin/

Edit: Ensure that your server is actually up and running first.

Comment: Link in the above post in misspelt - y and m interchanged. Try: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score -1):

You can find at http://localhost/phpymadmin/

just type the link above at your browser and make sure the server is running

Comment: Link in the above post in misspelt - y and m interchanged. Try: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/